# My comments on an Election and comment replies on an Election are showing in my Stack Overflow Activity tabs

Tags: bug, comments, comment-replies, activity-tab

Recently I have had a few comments, and replies, leak from a Stack Overflow Election page into my (main) Stack Overflow "Activity" tab. This has not happened before for me, as far as I recall. I wonder if this was a problem for a while, and has now been fixed, but I thought I would mention it in case it needs some investigation.

Here are four comments from me that I made on a Stack Overflow Election, showing on my main profile:

[image: Stack Overflow -> Activity -> All Actions -> Comments]

They can be told apart from normal comments because they do not have a title here.

Here is a single comment reply which I received on an Election page, shown in my Stack Overflow profile:

[image: Stack Overflow -> Activity -> Responses]

Again it can be seen that this one does not have a title.

The comments and comment replies can still be seen, at the time of writing, in the [Nomination phase of the 12th Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12?tab=nomination#post-62781103), under Dharman's post.

If a SO engineer can delete these from the histories of affected folks, that is ideal, but there's no worries on my side if it is not possible. The bigger issue here is perhaps looking at why this happened, and whether the bug is still present.

### Update

My original report here incorrectly suggested these messages were from Meta, when in fact they were from an Election. I am less inclined to think they are in the wrong place now, but if they *are* in the right place, then there is still a potential bug - the comments and replies are missing titles.

Comment: I just looked back and found I had made a comment in the March 2019 election and it is also displayed in the activity tab in this same way.

Comment: Thanks @DavyM. I have added an update - perhaps it is meant to be like this. If so, I wonder if those entries could do with a title, e.g. "Moderator Election 12".

Comment: This is normal and expected behavior. Your comments on the nomination post *are* made on Stack Overflow, and they're part of your Stack Overflow activity. Where else should they go? A revamp of the election system is underway, so now would be the time to recommend another place. Perhaps they would make more sense associated with your Meta account? But then you'd need a Meta account to be able to participate in the election.

Comment: @Cody: fair enough. However, comments made during a nomination phase are always available (e.g. here is [the Nomination phase for Election 11](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11?tab=nomination)). Thus, I think titles should be rendered here, linked to the appropriate page/tab. At the moment the comment/response entries are not clickable.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. They should actually be linked to the specific comment, as with all the other comments there, but for some reason that support was removed in the current election system. That should be coming back with the redesign.

Comment: @halfer IMO since the election pages are featured prominently it doesn't make much sense repeating those comments in the user profile comment history that is mostly for programming issues.

Comment: @bad_coder: that would be best raised as a separate Meta post, I think. My report here says "it's fine to have them in a user profile, but they are missing titles", whereas your report is "please remove them from the user profile".